# Trigger to add all prices of sold items and output to invoice table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables: items, sold, and invoice. The item table tracks individual item prices and descriptions, the sold table tracks items the belonging to a particular invoice, and Invoice tracks the date and other information. Invoice has a one-to-many relationship with sold and sold has a one-to-many relationship with items.

Here are the relevant columns in my tables: invoice(invoiceID, total) sold(soldID, invoiceID, itemID) item(itemID, description, price)

I currently have no way to track the total price for the invoice without manually summing the items. The total column in invoice must be manually inserted.

I'm looking to create a trigger the finds all the rows i sold that have a matching foreign key for invoiceID, then adds the prices of the relevant items and outputs that to invoice.

If this is not possible, I could also add a new price column to sold, then use multiple triggers to eventually work my way up to invoice.

I'm not in a position where I can make any significant changes to the structure of the database, so if possible it'd be best to keep the fields and relationships as is.

If anyone has any input on how to create this trigger it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stop right there. Drop the column `total` in `invoice`. Do not materialize this value. Keep the data redundancy-free. You can always query the sum of prices for an invoice. That'll always give you the right value. For convenience you can create a view that queries the invoices along with their prices.

Comment: @stickybit For the sake of my work, it would be much easier to have total in invoice. I manage everything through one form and also need to generate reports. I would have to spend an astronomical amount of hours changing my hole environment for your method to be optimal unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it would be the right end to change the front end. The database should store the data in optimal way to stay consistent, not in a way optimal for presentation. Changing the database here is definitively the wrong end to change.

Comment: @stickybit I guess I'm not seeing the logic here. What are the disadvantages of having a column that totals up the prices from the sold items? I can't help but feel that it would be less bloated and more elegant than having more queries/views to manage. Also, is it still data redundancy when the data is coming from a calculated field? Plus, your method would cause more inconsistencies. If I run a new query every time to find invoice totals, the total will change whenever I change the individual price of an item; this will effect past orders that have already been placed.

Comment: To address the problem with changing prices you may indeed need to copy data. That is, store the price an item was actually sold for in `sold`, if it can differ from the price in `item` (and take the sum from there).

Comment: The problem with materializing a total is that it can quickly lead to inconsistencies. A little error in your triggers may cause some change that isn't reflected and you have it. It can be done and in rare cases it might be the only way. But it takes great care and you can easily miss something. If it's avoidable, avoid it. You couldn't even recalculate it in your current model, since you lost the prices the items where actually sold for.

Comment: And queries (`SELECT`s) and view (actually stored `SELECT`s) never lead to any inconsistencies in the stored data. They're read only.

Answer (score 1):

@stickybit is exactly right. You don't want redundant data. You should not put any sort of derived total in an invoice record. Instead you should get it with a query or a view.

It's sometimes hard for people new to using SQL to believe, but queries and views are typically just as quick for retrieving aggregates like totals.

Views and tables look precisely the same from the perspective of application software. So make a view of your invoices that shows the totals. Something like this.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW invoice_with_totals AS
 SELECT sold.invoiceId, SUM(price) total
   FROM sold
   JOIN item ON sold.itemID = item.itemID
  GROUP BY invoiceID
```

Believe it or not, doing things this way with views will save you (or the people who will use your application) all kinds of troubleshooting craziness in the future. If you do things this way, there's simply no possibility of your totals disagreeing with the details in your invoices.  If you use a trigger, that's not guaranteed. And, you know, Murphy's law, big customer, incorrect invoice, you get the picture ....

I have hard-won experience backing up my suggestion. I suspect @stickybit does too. Please consider it.